# Nodejs - mongodb -- is there a simple way to get grouping/aggregate result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a node/express server that makes calls to mongodb. I try to make an aggregate request, and it kind of works, but I need to use .toArray().then()   to get the result, which feels rather weird. Surely there is an onther way?

```
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },function(err, db) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var dbo = db.db("mydb");

        var aggregateConditions = [{$match : { id: 12 }}, {$group : { _id: 'test1', total_id: { $sum: 'id'}}}];
        dbo.collection("customers").aggregate(aggregateConditions, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }else {
                res.toArray().then(x => console.log(x));

            }
        });

    });
    res.send({'test': 'Test executed'});
});
```

=> [ { _id: 'test1', total_id: 0 } ]

The result is also wrong. I would expect total_id to be 12, because I one document with {id : 12} in my collection.

EDIT :
Thanks to ColdHands:

> Official documentation specifies using Promise then function since as official docs say: You cannot return a cursor from a Function. Instead, evaluate the cursor using cursor.next() or cursor.toArray() and return the result

Thats what I needed to know.

Comment: Use `await` to avoid using Promise-style with `.then()`

Comment: Do you want to get rid of then call or your aggregate works not as expected? If first use await as @JeremyThille said, and if second, it would be helpful to have more info.

Official documentation specifies using `Promise` `then` function since as official docs say: _You cannot return a cursor from a Function. Instead, evaluate the cursor using cursor.next() or cursor.toArray() and return the result._